# Plot: x must be a label or position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph but I get ValueError: x must be a label or position

```
    Calc_height distribution avg_overall_rating avg_potential   avg_weight
0   165.0         74          67.365543        73.327754        139.459459
1   168.0         118         67.500518        73.124182        44.127119
2   170.0         403         67.726903        73.379056        147.799007
3   173.0         530         66.980272        72.848746        152.824528
4   175.0         1188        66.805204        72.258774        156.111953
5   178.0         1489        66.367212        71.943339        160.665547
6   180.0         1388        66.419053        71.846394        165.261527
7   183.0         1954        66.634380        71.754555        170.167861
8   185.0         1278        66.928964        71.833475        174.636933
9   188.0         1305        67.094253        72.151949        179.278161
10  191.0         652         66.997649        71.846159        184.791411
11  193.0         470         67.485141        72.459225        188.795745
12  195.0         211         67.425619        72.615373        196.464455
```

While trying to plot

```
players_height.plot(x=['Calc_height'],y=['avg_overall_rating'],figsize=(12,5),title='Potential vs Height')
```

Comment: I suggest studying the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot). Your use case is one of the first examples, and it explains that you should provide the column names as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments `x` and `y` take labels (strings) as input.

```
players_height.plot(x='Calc_height', y='avg_overall_rating', figsize=(12,5), title='Potential vs Height')
```